# Formatting issue with Ruby and puts

Tags: ruby

When we were younger, my friend and I had our own secret language. Recently he challenged me to make a translator so that I could input a word and it would convert it to the right word. It's silly, but it was just for fun.

The problem I have is that the converted word output is on separate lines.

What it should do:

Word to translate: Banana

Translated word: ananabang

What it does:

Word to translate: Banana

Translated word:

anana

bang

This is the code I've written.

```
puts "Enter word to translate \n \n"    
input = gets
firstCharacter = input[0].chr 
ang = "ang"

if firstCharacter =~ /\A(a|b|c|d|A|B|C|D)\Z/
        input.slice!(0)
        puts firstCharacter + input + "ang" 
end
```

I wonder if anyone can help me with the outputting issue..?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Fixed it with gets.chomp.

Answer (score 4):

`gets` returns the entered string with a newline at the end. If you change your second line to `input = gets.chomp`, it will work as expected because `chomp` removes the trailing newline.

Comment: Thanks, I realised after I'd posted it that I missed that out!

Answer (score 1):

You can also refactor your code into something more concise and clear:

```
print "Enter word to translate: "
word = gets.chomp.downcase
puts word.sub(/^(.)/, '') << "#{$1}ang"
```

Or slightly more verbosely:

```
print "Enter word to translate: "
word = gets.chomp.downcase
translation = word[1,1000] << word[0,1]
translation << 'ang'
puts translation
```

There are a lot of ways to do anything in Ruby, and it often pays to step back and consider whether you're overengineering when you could be creating something simpler and more maintainable.